# On three-finger-swipe down: execute custom command or keyboard stroke

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, gesture

macOS has built-in funcitonality to [drag stuff around with three-finger gestures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204609), but I want the gesture to close the current window.

I had [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) configured to send `CMD-W` keystroke on my old mac and it worked... but I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner solution that doesn't require me to run an app in the background the whole time...

Comment: Stick with BTT. It is the best way of doing this - and so much more.

Comment: @Gilby thanks, the "so much more" is exactly what concerns me a bit... I don't need or what any of the other functionality :P but yeah, if it's the only game in town, I'll have to shell out the $20 or whatever for an updated license...